# Is it ok to have no newline at end of /etc/group?

Tags: text-processing, group, file-format

I ran into a problem on busybox where my /etc/group file was not properly processed.

```
bash> tail /etc/group
...
onebutlast::1001:user1,user2
last::1002:user3bash>
```

The `user3` was not in the `last` group according the the [`getgrouplist`  function](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getgrouplist.3.html).

Verifying the `man group` page:

> The  /etc/group  file  is  a  text file that defines the groups on the system.
>          There is one entry per line, with the following format:

```
       group_name:password:GID:user_list
```

A hint in the right direction.  But it says nothing about what a 'line' is expected to be.

Easy enough to fix.  But my question is: is there some documentation/specification that specifies that the /etc/group file should have a newline as last character?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A "line" is [by definition](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_206) a string of text terminated by a newline.

By extension of this definition, a file is not a ["text file"](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_403) if it does not end with a newline character.

That's what POSIX says.  That standard does however not care about the `/etc/group` file as such (the group database may be stored in any sort of database, for example in a plain text file or an LDAP server, as long as it contains at least the group name, numerical group ID, and a list of users allowed in the group).  If the documentation on your system says that this file has to be a text file, then it needs to have a final terminating newline character.