# How to generate URL+title from URL list automatically? (using bash or other tool)

Tags: text-processing, url

Using Linux Bash, how can one turn a text file with:

```
http://example.org/
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mGQFZxIuURE
```

into:

```
http://example.org/ Example Domain
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mGQFZxIuURE Mike Perry - The Ocean (ft. Shy Martin) - YouTube
```

or into:

```
http://example.org/
Example Domain

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page 
Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mGQFZxIuURE
Mike Perry - The Ocean (ft. Shy Martin) - YouTube
```

?

How can one

1. pull a URL from a list of URLs in a file,
2. load the page,
3. extract its page title,
4. add that page title following that URL on the same line as the URL or on the line immediately following, then

perform those steps 1-4 for each subsequent URL in that list?

If not using Linux Bash, what other way is there?

Comment: bash isn't (much of) a text processing tool

Comment: @JeffSchaller How can it be done then? How can one turn an extermely long URL list (e.g. list of YouTube videos) into URL + title?

Comment: I'm sure you'll have several good answers momentarily; just because bash is your shell doesn't mean it has to do *everything*.  If you can spell out exactly how you want the transformation to happen, that would help answerers. How did you get "Example Domain" out of "http://example.org", for example(!) ?  Are you sending a request to that URL and extracting an HTML tag?

Comment: @JeffSchaller “Example Domain” is the title of the page. It is inside the `<title>` tags.

Comment: That should go ^^^ up in your Question as an edit, please & thank you!

Comment: I'd recommend using Perl rather than bash scripting. Text processing is Perl's speciality.

Answer (score 7):

With `curl` and [pup](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup):

```sh
while IFS= read -r url
do
   printf "%s " "$url"
   curl -sL "$url" | # fetch the page
       pup 'head title:first-of-type text{}' # get the text of the first title tag in head
done < input
```

Comment: Works but seems to require a blank line at the end of the input file. Otherwise, the last URL in the file isn't processed.

Comment: Not a blank line, just a newline at the end. That's the [definition of a line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/524442/70524)

Comment: You're right: a newline. Just pointed it out since the prob manifests if you paste a bunch of URLs in a text editor and neglect to hit Enter at the end of the last URL in the list.

Comment: @DavidYockey You don't need an additional Enter at the end if you use a proper text editor, e.g. vim, emacs.

Comment: @Sparhawk Wasn't aware of that diff between editors. Good to know. In using vim for serious stuff and a simple GUI editor for quickie cut & paste bits, guess I never noticed.

Comment: Even with GUI editors, maybe try something like VSCode or similar sensible ones: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/12076#issuecomment-272915821

Comment: FWIW even Kate and LibreOffice Writer save a newline at the end

Comment: Geany saves with a newline at the end, and I use it from time to time. For trivial stuff, like a quick c&p or writing up comments before posting, I usually just pull up Leafpad (http://tarot.freeshell.org/leafpad/). But it's now clear that Leafpad's to be avoided for anything code-related.

Comment: Doesn't appear to handle characters such as `™` and diaeresis (Ä, Ö, Å).